# Dependency injection (dynamic objects)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this dependency injection

```
public static class ServiceContainer
        {
            public static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
            {
                // Configuración de la cadena de conexión
                string connectionString = "Server=19209;Database=PODB;User Id=sa;Password=SSQL";
                var services = new ServiceCollection();
                services.AddSingleton<IDataConnection>(new DataConnection(connectionString));
                services.AddScoped(typeof(ISqlRepository<>), typeof(SqlRepository<>));
                services.AddScoped (typeof(IDatabaseService), typeof(DatabaseService<ExpandoObject>));
                return services.BuildServiceProvider();
            }
        }
```

on this line

```
services.AddScoped (typeof(IDatabaseService), typeof(DatabaseService<Customer>));
```

I have an object called Customer defined,
when starting the application
In the main form I have this button that fires the method and sends the customer object

```
public partial class StartMenu : Form
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseService _Dservice;
        public StartMenu(IDatabaseService service)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Dservice = service;
        }

        private async void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Id = 1;
            var param = new { Id };
            var customer = await _Dservice.GetAllAsync<Customer>("GetCustomerById", param);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customer;
        }
    }
}
```

Up to here everything works correctly.

But my problem is that in the mapping I cannot define the Default Client, that is to say that in this line

```
 services.AddScoped (typeof(IDatabaseService), typeof(DatabaseService<Customer>));
```

It should fit what I'm sending because I'm going to be running several different objects, not just client.

I know that if I put this object as dynamic it fixes this problem

**axample**

```
  services.AddScoped (typeof(IDatabaseService), typeof(DatabaseService<dynamic>));
```

But it also forces me to put it dynamic here

```
public partial class StartMenu : Form
    {
        private readonly IDatabaseService _Dservice;
        public StartMenu(IDatabaseService service)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Dservice = service;
        }

        private async void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Id = 1;
            var param = new { Id };
            var customer = await _Dservice.GetAllAsync<dynamic>("GetCustomerById", param);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customer;
        }
    }
}
```

And what I need is that the mapping is dynamic and in the form I can send any object

something like this

```
 services.AddScoped (typeof(IDatabaseService), typeof(DatabaseService<dynamic>));
  var customer = await _Dservice.GetAllAsync<Customer>("GetCustomerById", param);
```

I got the following error

**Unable to cast object of type 'DapperRow' to type 'DomainLayer.Customer'.**